# How can I build my onReceive method in my Android Widget class to toggle the image of an ImageView?

Tags: android, widget, imageview, toggle

Thanks to some tutorials I have now built my first working little Android Widget.

It has an ImageView which changes it's image when I click on it once.

But now I want to click on it multiple times to change to another image just like a toggle button.

Therefore I've set the following IF constraint in my onReceive method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
         try {                       
            if(counter %2 == 0) {
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv1, R.drawable.button_state1);                     
            cn1 = new     (context, MyDailyPlateWidgetProvider.class);  
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn1, views);

            counter++;
            } else { counter++;
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv1, R.drawable.button_state2);                          
            cn2 = new     (context, MyDailyPlateWidgetProvider.class);                  
            AppWidgetManager..getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn2, views);
            }
        }

    // ...
}
```

But it seems to me that I can't modify my `int counter` with `counter++` persistently.

Is there any way to set the int of my class through a click on my widget or an other solution to build some kind of toggle behavior in a widget?

Is this even possible without a running background service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Else, you fail to increment the counter. Imagine counter is first 0, so then (counter %2 == 0) is true, so it does the first part, and increments the counter. Next time counter is 1, so (counter %2 == 0) is false, so it does the second part... every time from then on, because counter is forever 1! Just increment counter every time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I edited the code wrong in here, I initially did have an second counter++ in the Else statement. But it didn't even change to the other image even though the counter should have been 1 after the first click on the Image.

Comment: How about you edit your question and copy-paste your actual executable code? What you have there currently is nonsense.